Как убрать лишние столбцы в запросе SQL?

Как убрать лишние столбцы в запросе, чтобы вместо id_rented_car писалось модель авто и вместо id_user, его имя, остальные столбцы из join не нужны. Запрос: SELECT * FROM orders  INNER JOIN Cars ON (id_rented_car = id_car)  INNER JOIN Users ON (id_customer = id_user)

Обозначьте необходимые столбцы после SELECT, вместо использования *.

Запрос должен быть текстом, а не картинкой. Нужные поля перечисляйте после select, для изменения названия в выводе используйте алиасы

@SwaD, прошу прощения, я не правильно понял вас, спасибо за очередную помощь :)

Как уже сказали в комментариях, чтобы вывести только необходимые столбцы необходимо указать их после SELECT заместо * - это выводит все столбцы.
К примеру если требуется вывести столбцы: id_order, start_date, expiration_date, model, price и username,  то запрос будет выглядеть так:
SELECT id_order, start_date, expiration_date, model, price, username
FROM orders
INNER JOIN Cars ON (id_rented_car = id_car)
INNER JOIN Users ON (id_customer = id_user);

